# Basis of image of matrix

Tags: matrices

I've got the matrix that looks like this $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 1 & -2\\0 & 2 & 2 & -5 \\ 4 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 3 & 1 & -5 \\ 4 & -2 & -1 & 9\end{bmatrix}$. After some row operations I get that matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 1 & -2\\0 & 2 & 2 & -5 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -2\end{bmatrix}$. Now i know that if i multiply it by $\begin{bmatrix}x1\\x2\\x3\\x4\end{bmatrix}$, the vector I get as a result has all parameters dependent on x4. How do I prove now, that the image of this matrix is the span of the first 3 columns?

Comment: The first 3 columns are pivot, so the first 3 columns form a basis for the column space.

Comment: I can't grasp what pivot is, care to explain?

Comment: A pivot column is a column which has a leading entry in the row-echelon form. A leading entry of a row is the first non-zero entry (from the left) in the row-echelon form.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I know that the columns in row-echelon form form a column space basis, but what about the columns in first matrix? Doesn't it change if I do the row operations and not the column operations?

Comment: The linear relations of the columns are preserved under row operations.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I even got another way of proving that after reading some stuff, but your way is simpler :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 3 columns are pivot, so the first 3 columns form a basis for the column space, which is the image of the matrix. This is due to the fact that the linear relations of the columns are preserved under elementary row operations.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively and more directly, you can transpose the matrix first, then row reduce the  transposed matrix. As the non-zero rows are linear combinations of the original transposed matrix rows with the same index, you know these are a basis of the image of the associated endomorphism.